# Webpack. Can`t understand why the project does not start ("Cannot GET /")

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

After I enter the command "npm start" in the terminal, everything seems to be fine, there are no errors

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
```

but in the browser message "Cannot GET /". I can't figure out what's wrong with the configuration and why is this message in the browser?

The project folder looks like this:

[image]

"package.json" file configuration

```
{
  "name": "Drag_n_Drop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.8",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.16.8"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js file configuration:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/app.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: 'dist'
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
            
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    }
}
```

app.ts content:

```js
import {CreateNewDesc, createDeskBtn} from './CreateNewDesc'
import {Task, createTskBtn} from './Task'


const mainDesk = document.querySelector('.main-desk')! as HTMLElement;
const projectWrapper = document.querySelector('.project-wrapper')! as HTMLDivElement;
let currentItem: HTMLDivElement;





createTskBtn?.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    new Task(mainDesk)
})
createDeskBtn?.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    new CreateNewDesc(projectWrapper);
})


function dragStartHandler(event: any){
    if(event.target.className === 'task'){
    currentItem = event.target;
    }
    }
function dragEnterHandler(event: any){
    if(event.target.className === 'desk')
    {
         event.target.style.opacity = '.5'
    }}
function dragLeaveHandler(event: any){
    if(event.target.className === 'desk')
    {
        event.target.style.opacity = '1'
    }}
document.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler);
document.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnterHandler);
document.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeaveHandler);
    
document.addEventListener('dragover', (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
});

function dropHandler(event: any){
if(event.target.className === 'desk'){
    event.target.style.opacity = '1'
    currentItem.parentNode?.removeChild(currentItem)
    event.target.appendChild(currentItem);
}
    }
    document.addEventListener('drop', dropHandler);
```

Comment: can you show your app.ts? the server is running fine but you have tell him what to do when he receive a get request on '/', if you don't you get that message

Comment: @coglialoro Added. Could you suggest how to fix this? I don't know much about webpack yet.

Comment: oh sorry, i tought you were building a server with node. i think you just have to instruct webpack-dev-server to serve the `dist` folder, also i think your `index.html` and `style.css` files needs to be inside the `dist` folder aswell

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: can you try add: `devServer: {contentBase: "./dist"},` to your webpack config object

Comment: And now it throws new error: ```[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'contentBase'.```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243021/discussion-between-coglialoro-and--).